# Item$.take is not a function TypeError: item$.take is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6

I face a problem regarding take(1) is not a function of angular firebase object.
I can try with valuechages or snapshotchanges but this could not help for me as I have to use but there are other problem.I am using angular 6.

Here is my version details:-

```js
Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.5
@angular/cli                      6.2.5
@angular/fire                     5.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.5
@schematics/angular               0.8.5
@schematics/update                0.8.5
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.20.2
```

In case of subscribe method I face with same problem.

Here is my code:-

```html
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService  {



  suscription: Subscription ;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.updateItemQty(product, 1);
  }

  async removeFromCart(product) {
    this.updateItemQty(product, -1);
  }

  async getCart() {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId)

  }

  async clearAllCart() {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId).remove();
  }

  private async updateItemQty(product: Product, change: number) {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    const item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key);
    item$.take(1).subscribe(item => {
      const quantity = (item.quantity || 0) + change;
      if (quantity === 0) { item$.remove(); } else { item$.update({
        title: product.title,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        price: product.price,
        quantity: quantity
      });
      }
    });
  }

  private createCartId() {
    return this.db.list('shopping-cart').push({
      dateTime: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId(): Promise<string> {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cardId');
    if (cartId) { return cartId; }

    const cart = await this.createCartId();

    cartId = localStorage.getItem('cardId');
    if (cartId) { return cartId; }

    localStorage.setItem('cardId', cart.key);
    return cart.key;
  }

  private getItem(cartId, key) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId + '/items/' + key);
  }

}
```

So , I can't use snapshotchanges() and valuechanges() because then I am unable to use or I got error like-item.quantity,item$.remove and item$.update.

Why take(1) or  subscribe is not function for  @angular/fire                     5.1.0?

Please suggestion or any alternative way to implement.

Comment: try to remove the first import 'import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';' which is rxjs 5 import style

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular 6, it uses rxjs version 6.
In this rxjs version the way you use "take" (and other operators) has changed.

you'll need to convert your code like this

```
item$.pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe(item => {
            const quantity = (item.quantity || 0) + change;
            if (quantity === 0) { item$.remove(); } else { item$.update({
                title: product.title,
                imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
                price: product.price,
                quantity: quantity
            });
            }
        });
```

Also you'll need to change import statement to

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```